# Incorrect output for if-else block

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is the parent class

```
class Car():
def __init__(self, company_name, year, model_name):
    self.company_name = company_name
    self.year = year
    self.model_name = model_name
    self.odometer_reading = 0

def display_info(self):
    print(self.company_name.title() + ' ' + self.model_name.title() + ' ' + str(self.year))

def change_reading(self, odometer_reading):
    self.odometer_reading += odometer_reading

def read_reading(self):
    print("Miles: " + str(self.odometer_reading))
```

This is the child class

```
class ElectricCar(Car):
def __init__(self, company_name, year, model_name):
    super().__init__(company_name, year, model_name)

def battery_size(self, model):
    if (model == 'e'):
        self.model_name = model
        self.battery = 70
    elif (model == 'x'):
        self.model_name = model
        self.battery = 90
    else:
        self.model_name = model
        self.battery_size = 80
    print("Model " + self.model_name.title() + " has " + str(self.battery) + "kWh battery")
```

After creating an instance of the class and calling it, I'm able to get the output as reqd

```
ecar1 = ElectricCar('tesla', 2017, 'e')
ecar1.battery_size('e')
ecar1.battery_size('x')
```

But for the given statement, I'm unable to do so. Why?

```
ecar1.battery_size('faraday')
```

Comment: Look closely at the difference between the code after "elif" and the code after "else".

Comment: Yes. Thank you. It was a silly mistake on my part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your else statement, you have

```
self.battery_size = 80
```

It should be

```
self.battery = 80
```